# Strange error clearing behavior when validating group

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate, and setup a group so it only shows a single error message when any of my required fields are invalid. The error is being thrown correctly, but I'm running into a problem whenever there are multiple invalid fields. For some reason, jquery clears the error message when the first invalid field is cleared. It doesn't seem to consider the fact that there may be other invalid fields that have yet to be fixed. I need the error message to stay put until the last invalid item in the group has been cleared.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    jQuery.validator.messages.required = "Please complete the required fields.";
    $("#quote").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#error-note",
        rules: {
            serviceDate: "required",
            recurringBasis: "required"
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().prev().prev('span').addClass("error");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().prev().prev('span').removeClass("error");
        },
        groups: {
            collecive: "serviceDate recurringBasis"
        }
    });

});
```

Here's [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRWgv/) to help demonstrate what I'm talking about.

I need the group error message "Please complete the required fields." to stay put until the last invalid item in the group has been cleared. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be a bug and the developer was the last to comment about it:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since this seems to be a bug](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/364), there's not a lot that can be done here.  (*I believe discussion about fixing bugs and modifying the plugin's source code should be confined to the developer's official GitHub repository.*)

Otherwise, setting the `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` options to `false` will force the form 
validation test to only occur when the submit button's `click` event occurs.  Not ideal, but perhaps an acceptable workaround until the bug is fixed.

```
$("#quote").validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vRWgv/3/